# What privileges do I need in order to grant execute on dbms_rls?

Tags: oracle

I have an automated build script that creates a new user and builds up a schema. I also want to `grant execute on dbms_rls to myuser` as part of this script, but I am getting this error:

```
Error starting at line : 3 in command -
grant execute on sys.dbms_rls to chemreg
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
```

I can successfully execute `grant execute on dbms_rls to myuser` if I am running as SYS, but my build script will be running as another user.  Which privileges does that user require in order to grant execute on dbms_rls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which privileges does that user require in order to grant execute on dbms_rls?

The grating user should have the `execute` privilege on `DBMS_RLS` with [GRANT OPTION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01603).

I have two users namely `usra` and `usrb`. I have granted `execute` on `DBMS_RLS` to `usra` with admin option. Then `usra` is able to grant the privilege to `usrb`.

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
SQL> grant execute on dbms_rls to usra with grant option;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn usra/usra
Connected.
SQL> grant execute on sys.dbms_rls to usrb;

Grant succeeded.
```

Comment: Excellent.  `with grant option` works like a charm.  Thanks!